# speech_recognition PySide2 .QtGui has no attribute QApplication

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def recognize():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    with sr.AudioFile("test.wav") as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    
    print(r.recognize_google(audio))
    
recognize()
```

The first time I ran the code, it said that PySide2 is not installed, now when I installed it, it gives this error

```
Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\matplotlibtools.py", line 30, in do_enable_gui
    enable_gui(guiname)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 540, in enable_gui
    return gui_hook(app)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 180, in enable_qt
    self.enable_qt4(app)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 205, in enable_qt4
    app, inputhook_qt4 = create_inputhook_qt4(self, app)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhookqt4.py", line 84, in create_inputhook_qt4
    app = QtGui.QApplication([" "])
AttributeError: module 'PySide2.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'
Backend QtAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```